# Openlayers text label

Tags: javascript, openlayers

i was wondering if there is any way to add a text label to a open layers map.

I want to insert the name of i.e a ship next to the ships marker, and i need to be able to turn each individual text label on/off programatically.

I do see that there is a popup option, but this is far from what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could take a look here: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/vector-features-with-text.html

You basically use the StyleMap to style your text and then use an `attributes` object to determine your label text, etc. for each point.

Comment: yeah iknow, i did look into that one - but by the looks of it, it does not seem to be able to turn it on/off programatically - it just stays on all the time.

Comment: To turn it off/on programaticlly, all you need to do is toggle styleMap object

Comment: Looks like i cant even add a label to it!

`var marker_style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            'default': {
                label: "${id}",
                fontSize: "12px",
                fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
                fontWeight: "bold"
            }
        });
        
        var markers_map = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers('Markers', {styleMap: marker_style});`

- It does not show up

Comment: Markers are deprecated stuff, should use vector layer with point geometries.

Comment: Markers are not deprecated.  Not only that but they are also part of a 'feature' which is the base class for a vector feature.